# Is there any security difference between login via iFrame, Pop-up, or redirect?

Tags: authentication, facebook, oauth2, iframe, single-sign-on

There seems to be a number of techniques to authenticate a person on the web. Most commonly there are

- Javascript Pop-ups (Google, Firefox Persona, Disqus, etc)
- HTTP Redirects (OAuth, Facebook)
- [IFrames](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/sandboxed-iframes/), with sandboxing set as needed.

**Question**

Is one approach more secure than the others? What are the tradeoffs?

Come to think of it, I think Facebook may offer both OAuth Redirects and a JS based popup.

Comment: Are you exclusively referring to authentication on third-party sites? I'm asking because I don't see Google doing pop-ups by default.

Comment: if the popup is a window, they should be the same, if the rules are being enforced.

Answer (score 4):

Iframes are dangerous as the user has no easy way of verifying that the embedded page is indeed, say, *facebook.com* and not some phishing page. Depending on how it is set up, allowing embedding might also enable [clickjacking](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Clickjacking).

Using a popup versus redirecting the current page is just a matter of user experience and has no impact on security.

Answer (score 1):

To the question of popups there is less of a security concern versus a UX concern.  Many browsers and their anti-nuisance plugins may prevent popups from working as expected.  Redirects tend to be cleaner, particularly for mobile devices such as phones and tablets.

Comment: E.g. Facebook embedded (in-app) safari browser on iPhone will never display a popup and the market share of this (horrific) browser is too significant to ignore for some sites.